# Is it possible to add language ckeditor scayt spell checker?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, scayt

I saw the [ckeditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_scayt) webpage that the default languages are: en_US, en_GB, pt_BR, da_DK, nl_NL, en_CA, fi_FI, fr_FR, fr_CA, de_DE, el_GR, it_IT, nb_NO, pt_PT, es_ES, and sv_SE.

Is it possible to add new languages for the spell checker? for example slovak or hungarian or serbian languages. Thanks for the helps or information!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that SpellCheckAsYouType (SCAYT) functionality is built-in by default into CKEditor. However, it is a standalone solution provided bt WebSpellChecker LLC company. Thus all your technical or business-relative questions you can address directly to support@webspellchecker.net.

The additional languages (f.e. Slovak, Hungarian) can be added to the Licensed or Hosted Paid version of the WebSpellChecker application.

The full list of available additional languages you can find here: http://www.webspellchecker.net/additional-languages-support.html

You can evaluate spelling check in a chosen Additional language on the appropriate demo page: http://www.webspellchecker.net/samples/additional-languages-demo.html#lang-code

Also, you can ask a vendor to add the language to your Hosted trial account for evaluation purposes on a temporary basis.